# Extracting and storing data from a very large file in R

Tags: r

I have a very large DAT file (16 GB). It contains some information of let's say, 1000 customers. This data is sorted like below that the first column is representing the customer IDs:

```
9909814 246766  0   31/07/2012 7:00 0.03    0   0   0   0
8211675 262537  0   8/04/2013 3:00  0.52    0   0   0   0
```

However, the data of customers are not stored in an organized way. So, I want to extract the data of each customer and store it in a separate file. (I have a file that contains the customer IDs. )

For just one customer, I wrote the following code that can search through the file and extract data. However, my problem is to how to do this for all the customers when I'm reading this big file into R.

```
con<-file('D:/CD_INTERVAL_READING.DAT')
open(con)
n=20
nk=100000
B=9909814   #customer ID for customer no.1 
customer1 <- read.table(con, sep=",",  nrow=1)
for (i in 1:n) {
  conn <- read.table(con,sep=",",skip=(i-1)*nk, nrow=nk)
 ## extracts just those rows that belong to a specific customer ID  
  temp1 <-conn[conn$V1==B,]
customer1 <-rbind(customer1,temp1)
}
customer1 <- customer1 [-1,]

library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(customer1, "D:/customer1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a computer with limited memory? Also, have you considered reading in chunks of the file at a time? You can read more about that [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/72295_692737b667614d369bd87cb0f51c9a4b.html)

Comment: Thanks, I can use uni facilities for fast processing. Actually, Maybe, my main problem is a bit simple. I mean I don't know how to define a file for each customer. I need for example to define files named customer1, customer2, etc and write data into them.

Comment: Each line is a customer? And for each customer, you want write a new file?

Comment: Yes, each line includes the information of a customer, but thousands of lines are available for each customer in an unorganized way. I want to extract the data of all customers when I read through the file in an efficient way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution would probably be to import the data into a proper database but if you really want to split the file into multiple files based on the first token then you can use `awk` with this one-liner.

```
awk '/^/ {ofn=$1 ".txt"} ofn {print > ofn}' filetosplit.txt
```

It works by

- `/^/` matching start of line
- `{ofn=$1 ".txt"}` sets the `ofn` variable to the first word (split by white space) with `.txt` appended.
- Print each line to the file set by `ofn`.

It takes me just under two minutes on my laptop to split a 1 GB file with the same format as you listed above into multiple text files. I have no idea how well that scales or if it's fast enough for you. If you want an R solution you can always wrap it into a `system()` call ;o)

**Addendum:**
Oh ... I'm guessing you are on windows based on the path you mentioned. Then you may need to install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) to get `awk`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, nice information for a beginner like me. Surely, can use it later for my simulations.